# Trying to minus a percentage from an already given figure in php

Tags: php, math, post

I have an already given number ($row['mhprice']  * $_POST['mh']) that works fine but I want to subtract a percentage 1 - 9 which is given in $_POST['clength']. So far I have the following:

```
$_POST['clength']; // = 4 for example

This would cost you <?php echo $row['mhprice']  * $_POST['mh'] - ($_POST['clength'] / 100) * 10; ?>
```

Comment: Basic math? If you're given 4 and want 4 percent of a number, move the decimal place to the left two places and multiply... `($_POST['clength'] * .01) * $row['mhprice']`. If you're given 4 and want 96 percent of the figure then `((100-$_POST['clength']) * .01) * $row['mhprice']`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user does not display basic knowledge of math.

Comment: Is there a stackoverflow for basic mathematics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
This would cost you <?php echo ($row['mhprice']  * $_POST['mh'] * (1 - $_POST['clength'] / 100)); ?>
```

In the example with 4, this would multiply `($row['mhprice']  * $_POST['mh'])` by `.96`, thereby reducing it by 4%.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help and no critisism, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Minus a percent :)

```
$pc = $_POST['clength'] / 100;
$price = $row['mhprice'] * $_POST['mh'];
$discounted_price = $price - ($price * $pc);
echo "This would cost you {$discounted_price}";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a math question but this should work (I removed the *10 at the end because I don't know what you were doing with that number.

```
<?php echo (($row['mhprice']  * $_POST['mh']) - (($row['mhprice']  * $_POST['mh'])*($_POST['clength'] / 100))); ?>
```